# Efficient way to sum on one column where count(value_1) / count(value_2) of another column is greater than x

Tags: sql, performance, out-of-memory, presto, memory-efficient

I have a table of the following structure:

```
| id | bool | amt |
-------------------
| 1  | 0    | 4   |
| 1  | 1    | 3   |
| 1  | 1    | 5   |
| 2  | 0    | 8   |
| 2  | 1    | 4   |
| 2  | 0    | 4   |
```

I want to get the sum of the `amt` but only when the the ratio of `bool = 1` / `bool = 0` per `id` is greater than 0.6.

I have successfully done this like this:

```
SELECT SUM(amt) as total_amt,
FROM table
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY id 
    HAVING CAST(SUM(bool) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(COUNT(bool) AS DOUBLE) > 0.6
)
```

However, my problem is that this is a toy simulation of my actual tables and data, and in reality it is a very large amount of data. When I run this query on all my data, I get errors either saying that the memory limit of the cluster has been reached, or that the execution time has reached the limit. If I remove the `WHERE` statement which finds the `id`s satisfying the ratio, then it runs without errors.

Before resorting to having these limits increased, is there any way I can achieve this more efficiently, either in terms of memory, execution time, or both?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select sum(id_amount)
from (select id, sum(amount) as id_amount,
             avg(case when bool then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio
      from t
      group by id
     ) t
where ratio > 0.6;
```

Note:  I don't have much experience with Presto.  I think you can use:

```
avg(bool)
```

or:

```
avg(bool::int)
```

instead of the above expression.